# Recycle View with card layout always same size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-design-library

I am implementing a recycle view with a card layout to do something like this:
[image]

the thing is, that I can't get a full width/height card layout, I just keep getting a low card layout like this:

[image: image2]

how can I adapt my example to get the result I desire?

I already have the adapter with all the info to stick it inside the card view, but somehow the layout is always that strange :S.

**Here is the XML of my mainLayout:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_plant_feed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_plant_feed"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_plant_feed_drawer"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


**and the row for the card layout:**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_specie_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/reportImg"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Avaliation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/plantName"
                android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:text="Avalie a fotografia" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reportImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/color_cursor_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/plantName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userIcon" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**activity code**

```
public class PlantFeed extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,PlantFeedAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    //initialize fields

    String token;

    ArrayList<PlantPhotoUser> photos = new ArrayList<>();

    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    final String GETREQUEST = "GETCALL";

    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/fotos";

    String date;
    String lat;
    String lon;
    String alt;

    PlantFeedAdapter plantFeedAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plant_feed);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),5);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        plantFeedAdapter = new PlantFeedAdapter(getApplicationContext(), photos,PlantFeed.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(plantFeedAdapter);

        token = checkForToken();

        initVolleyCallback();

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

        mVolleyService.getDataVolley(GETREQUEST,URL,token);

    }

    void initVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("HELLL","hi1");
            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
                PlantPhotoUser plantPhotoUser;
                Log.d("HELLLL","hi");
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("objeto",object.toString());

                        int userId = object.getInt("userId");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(userId));
                        String username = object.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(username));
                        int plantId = object.getInt("plantId");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(plantId));
                        String specie = object.getJSONObject("plant").getString("specie");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(specie));

                        String path = object.getString("image");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(path));
                        int fotoId = object.getInt("id");

                        if(object.getString("date") != null){
                            date = object.getString("date");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("lat") != null){
                            lat = object.getString("lat");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("lon") != null){
                            lon = object.getString("lon");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("altitude") != null){
                            alt = object.getString("altitude");
                        }

                        plantPhotoUser = new PlantPhotoUser(fotoId,plantId,userId,path,specie,date,lat,lon,alt,username);
                        photos.add(plantPhotoUser);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                plantFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("FAIL",error.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public String checkForToken() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tokenKey = getResources().getString(R.string.token);
        String token = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.token), tokenKey); // take the token
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.plant_feed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRowClick(int position, String name, int id, View view) {

    }
}
```

any help, please?

Thank you

Comment: Post your activity code.

Comment: done check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You are using `GridLayoutManager` for your `RecyclerView` with span count `5` that's why your `CardView` uses `1/5` spaces of total `screen-width`.

**Use `LinearLayoutManager` to show as `full-width` vertical list:**

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

**Instead of:**

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 5);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**2.** You have used `RecyclerView` width and height as `wrap_content`. Try using `match_parent`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: thank you very much, i can't move my recycle view a little bit down because i have a a custom toolbar and it places above it, do you know why?

Comment: Remove your `RecyclerView` from `DrawerLayout` and put in `app_bar_plant_feed` Under `AppBarLayout` because `DrawerLayout` can have at most two direct children. Also add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to RecyclerView xml to show it below ToolBar..

Comment: do i need to create the app_bar_plant_feed?

Comment: but isnt there a problem if i put it there, because i am reusing that layout in other activities without recycleview

Comment: In that case, you can create another layout with AppBarLayout and RecyclerView and include this layout and NavigationView into DrawerLayout.

Comment: seems fine, thank you a lot, just a last question, what is the best way to move the layout widgets inside the card? relative to each other?

Comment: you can use RelativeLayout for your attached layout image.

Comment: It depends. For example, layout contains an `image` and two `textview` at right of image . For this design you should use `toRightOf >> Image` to your `TextView` instead of adding left margin to `TextView` as per photo width. You can add margin for making gap between adjacent views.

Comment: You card layout seems fine